# Repetition occuring in Liebiniz? Where?

Tags: kierkegaard, leibniz

In *Repetition* by Soren Kierkegaard,there is a sentence which says this.

> Just as they taught that all-knowing is recollecting, modern philosophy will teach that all life is a repetition. The only modern philosopher who has had an intimation of this is **Leibniz**.

(I added **bold**)

What is this concept by Leibniz?

Does it differ from Kierkegaard's meaning of repetition which I understand as *an act once done, done again*.

Comment: What Kierkegaard has in mind here is murky. Lakke and Waaler suggest that he refers to ideally existing essences in God's mind being "repeated" in the creation, as laid out in *Theodicy*, just as agents "repeat" in their actions what they contemplated in deliberations, see [Traces of Kierkegaard's Reading of the Theodicy in Kierkegaard and the Renaissance and Modern Traditions, section V](https://books.google.com/books?id=JwWoDQAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: Leibniz has written a few pieces on Eternal Recurrence but until recent times they had remained unpublished (1991 ed. by Fichant).  Kierkegaard most probably knew about his "preformism" which the Encyclopedists also liked; see e.g. *Systeme nouveau* (1695). Hegel forcefully asserted that nature repeats itself, while society develops without ever repeating itself.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.